# Smartsheet Python SDK Copy Workspace Fails

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am trying to copy a workspace to get around the 100 object limit.

Here's my code:

```
def rg_copy_workspace(workspace_id, new_ws_name, api_token, debug=False):
import smartsheet
smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet(api_token)
smartsheet.errors_as_exceptions(True)

new_workspace = smartsheet.Workspaces.copy_workspace(
        workspace_id,
        smartsheet.models.ContainerDestination({
                'new_name': new_ws_name
        })
)
```

just like the example in the Python SDK.

I am testing on a workspace with a small number of objects (I started with only one Sheet)
I'm getting an error on the folder_obj. I have tried it with and without a folder, and when I have a folder with and without contents.

rg_copy_workspace(workspace_id, new_ws_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    rg_copy_workspace(workspace_id, new_ws_name)

File "", line 15, in rg_copy_workspace
    'new_name': new_ws_name

File "(path-deleted)\workspaces.py", line 80, in copy_workspace
    folder_obj = Folder({

File "(path-deleted)\smartsheet.py", line 210, in request
    """

File "(path-deleted)\smartsheet.py", line 278, in request_with_retry
    if 200 <= response.status_code <= 299:

File "(path-deleted)\smartsheet.py", line 244, in _request
    native = res.native(expected)

UnexpectedRequestError: (, None)

What am I doing wrong? I don't know how the code makes it to line 80 of workspaces.py.

I updated to latest version of SDK this morning (after receiving the error)

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Reputation won't let me comment.

Your code seemed to execute fine for me on the updated 1.3 SDK.

The traceback locations look to lineup with sources from roughly a year ago, but linecache is pulling from the new source to build the traceback (smartsheet.py, line 210 is actually in a comment, so it's definitely not right). I'm not sure what all the situations are that could account for this but I'd guess there are compiled bytecode (.pyc) files somewhere that are stale.

Can you share a DEBUG level log near the relevant failure so that I can see what the API request looks like?

Comment: Hi Tim. I did not bring my work computer with me this weekend. I will reboot that computer when I get home and try again. I may not have restarted my IDE after updating the SDK. That is very possible, given my multi-tasking at the time.

Comment: This was resolved. I'm not sure how, probably with a more recent version of the SDK